# SSRS Report Builder 2016 - Calculating Debit and Credit and display to Balance row

Tags: reporting-services, report

Report builder design

[image]

Running expression inside FlineBalance properties

[image]

Expression inside FlineBlance

[image]

This is the result of may table however its wrong

[image]

This is the result that i am expecting basically this report is from crystal report and i am trying to convert this in SSRS

[image]

What expression should I use?

i tried below expression but it's not successful.

```
=IIF(Fields!debitAmount.Value > 0,Abs(Previous(Fields!FlineBalance.Value) + Fields!debitAmount.Value),
IIF(Fields!creditAmount.Value > 0,Abs(Fields!debitAmount.Value - Previous(Fields!FlineBalance.Value))
,Abs(Fields!FlineBalance.Value)))
```

[I revise the expression code to FlineBlance to: =IIF(Fields!debitAmount.Value > 0,Abs(Fields!FlineBalance.Value),
IIF(Fields!creditAmount.Value > 0,Abs(Previous(Fields!FlineBalance.Value) -Fields!creditAmount.Value)
,"")) but as you can see the higlighted yellow should be zero.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fSFJg.png)

Comment: I revise my expression to FlineBalance to like this:=IIF(Fields!debitAmount.Value > 0,Abs(Fields!FlineBalance.Value),
IIF(Fields!creditAmount.Value > 0,Abs(Previous(Fields!FlineBalance.Value) -Fields!creditAmount.Value)
 ,"")) and result like this

Answer (score 0):

Try the following for you FlineBalance expression

```
=RunningValue(Fields!debitAmount.Value, SUM, Nothing) - RunningValue(Fields!cerditAmount.Value, SUM, Nothing)
```

Comment: If my answer resolved you issue, please mark the answer as accepted (the check mark to the left of the question below the vote up/down buttons)

Answer (score 0):

I have small issues only in the table below my first page. the bottom line its not showing in every page it's appearing only in the last page. kindly advise.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mLbRl.png)

Comment: You should delete this as it is not an answer. If you have another issue then you need to ask a new question. Remember that StackOverflow serves as a huge knowledge database and people will look for answers based on questions, like yours, that have been answered previously so it's important yo keep things as simple as direct as possible.